# Install rt3572 driver for Asus Usb-N53 Adapter

Tags: wireless, makefile

I recently bought the asus USB-N53 wireless adapter, and want to install the latest driver for it. It comes with instructions of how to install the driver from the files provided, but I can't use makefile, so can't install the driver correctly. These are the instructions from the readme file included:

=======================================================================

## Build Instructions:

1. `tar -jxvf 2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO.tar.bz2`
   go to `./2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO` directory.
2. switch to super user.
    ** for Fedora

   ```
   $ su
   ```

   ** for Ubuntu

   ```
   $ sudo su
   ```
3. in Makefile

   ```
   set the "MODE = STA" in Makefile and chose the TARGET to Linux by set "TARGET = LINUX"
   ```

   define the linux kernel source include file path `LINUX_SRC`
    modify to meet your need.
4. in `os/linux/config.mk` 
    define the `GCC` and `LD` of the target machine
    define the compiler flags `CFLAGS`
    modify to meet your need.

   ** Build for being controlled by NetworkManager or `wpa_supplicant` wext functions
      Please set `HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y` and `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y`.
      => #> `cd wpa_supplicant-x.x`
      => #> `./wpa_supplicant -Dwext -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d`

   ** Build for being controlled by WpaSupplicant with Ralink Driver
      Please set `HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y` and `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n`.
      => #> `cd wpa_supplicant-0.5.7`
      => #> `./wpa_supplicant -Dralink -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d`
5. compile driver source code
       $ make

=======================================================================

## Install Instructions:

1. load driver

   ```
      $ make install
   ```
2. plug in USB dongle.

=======================================================================

Can somebody help me to use makefile to install the driver?

EDIT:
When I ran `uname -R`, the terminal `outputted 3.2.0-58-generic-pae`.
When I ran `lsusb`, the terminal outputted:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0ac8:3450 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:179d ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05fc:0231 Harman Multimedia
```

Comment: Can you specifi exactly what your problem is?

Comment: Depending on your Ubuntu version, you will probably not succeed in installing this 2011 file. Please open the terminal and run and post: uname -r and also: lsusb.

Comment: My problem is I do not know how to do any of the steps after step 3

Answer (score 0):

I have doubt as to whether the relatively old file will compile, but you are using an older kernel; i.e. 3.2.0-58, so it may work. Let's try. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

In the folder you extracted, open os > linux > config.mk with any text editor, such as gedit. Change HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y and HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y. Save and close the text editor.

Now back to the terminal and change to the directory with the file; for instance:

```
cd ~/Desktop/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt3572sta
```

Let us know if you get an error or get stuck.